# sort table tr according to given condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**html** [JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/gP8VS/) 
**See first example home,Scripts,Snippet. if Script Parent is 1 it should under home tr,if Snippet parent id is 6 it is under the Script menu**

```
<table id="sort-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Parent</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>home</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Code</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Contact</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>PHP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Scripts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Archive</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Snippet</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>samitha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>help</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<span></span>

<br>
<button class="sort-table asc">sort</button>
```

**jquery**

```
 $('.sort-table').click(function (e) {


        var table = $("table tbody");

        table.find('tr').each(function () {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                id = $tds.eq(0).text(),
                parent = $tds.eq(1).text(),
                title = $tds.eq(2).text();

            if (parent === 0) {




            }

        });

    });
```

**output**

```
Id  Parent  Title
1   0       home
2   0       Code
3   0       Contact
4   10      PHP
5   2       CSS
6   1       Scripts
8   4       Archive
9   6       Snippet
10  0       samitha
7   4       help
```

I want to sort it like bellow

**2nd table**

```
   Id   Parent  Title
    1   0       home
    6   1       Scripts
    9   6       Snippet
    2   0       Code
    5   2       CSS
    3   0       Contact
    10  0       samitha
    4   10      PHP
    8   4       Archive
    7   4       help
```

I want if the parent Id is the id of menu it need to be sort like above 2nd table.I did something with and i need to go though on this ?

Comment: There's no apparent order !

Comment: see if the parent column id = menu Id it's need to be sort

Comment: See first example   home,Scripts,Snippet. if Script Parent is 1 it should under home tr,if Snippet parent id is 6 it is under the Script menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no apparent system to sort by, I guess you have to define something yourself :

```
$('.sort-table').click(function (e) {
    var sort  = [1,6,9,2,5,3,10,4,8,7],
        table = $("table tbody"),
        tr    = table.find('tr');

    $.each(sort, function(_,index) {
        tr.filter(function() {
            return parseInt($('td:first', this).text(), 10) == index;
        }).appendTo(table);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gP8VS/4/)

**EDIT:**

I think maybe I get it, but I probably don't?
If you are trying to add each TR element after the TR element that has the ID of the given parent element in the current TR etc... ???

Anyway, try this :

```
$('.sort-table').click(function (e) {
    var table = $("table tbody"),
        tr    = table.find('tr');

    $.each(tr, function(_,el) {
        var par = parseInt($(el).find('td').eq(1).text(), 10);
        if (par !== 0) {
            var par_el = tr.find('td:first').filter(function() {
                return parseInt($(this).text(),10) == par;
            }).closest('tr');
            par_el.after(el);
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gP8VS/8/)

Comment: This is a dynamic menu it will have 100 menus like this.So how would i update your code to work with all those menus

Comment: But there's nothing to sort by? It's not sorted alpabethically, not by numbers or ID, I don't understand how you get the order in the second list, there has to be some sort of system ?

Comment: It was generated menu using php+mysql+bootsramp.SO i want to show this menu as a tree in my admin panel.

Comment: See this example home,Scripts,Snippet. if Script Parent is 1 it should under home tr,if Snippet parent id is 6 it is under the Script menu

Comment: we don't know the id of the menu.

Comment: It's a nice menu, and i get that you're trying to sort submenus in some sort of strange order, and it could be me being stupid, but I just don't see how we are supposed to know what goes where?

Comment: Thanks man.That is the thing i want .How awesome it is.I'll give 100 Reputation for this later .You got me.Working nicely